# Optimization with a variable growing too much as we approach the minimum.

Tags: algorithms, nonlinear-optimization

I've been stuck in this problem for a while.

To illustrate it, consider the following nonlinear optimization problem:

> minimize $x$ subject to $xy=1$ and $x\geq 0$

It has no solution, but it does have lots of "quasi-solutions", which are $x=\varepsilon$ and $y=1/\varepsilon$, for each $\varepsilon>0$, and the quasi-solution gets better as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$.

> I would like to know if there is a general algorithmic way to find an $\varepsilon$-optimal solution for any given $\varepsilon$, not only to this specific problem, but to any similar problem, when a variable tends to infinity as we approach the minimum. If possible, avoiding numerical problems.

Thank you, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with $\varepsilon$-optimal?

Comment: In the example, an $\varepsilon$-optimal point is $(\varepsilon, 1/\varepsilon)$, which is not the minimum (because there is no actual solution), but in a sense, close to what seems to be the minimum "$(0,\infty)$", abusing the notation.